# Cannot read property 'length' of null, javascript. Check if given string contain letters: p & t

Tags: javascript, typeerror, variadic-functions, string-length

Im trying debug my JS mini projects. A few of them, shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
> at task(xx)

Those mini-projects works, but I would like to delete all the bugs.

This task is about: check whether a given string contains equal number of p's and t's.

I followed message of the bug, as I understand if the length of variable is null or 0, that means this is undefined and cannot be validated. So, unsuccesfully, I tried use this piece of code:

```
if (p < 0 || t< 0) 
or 
if (task55word == null)
```

The basic code is here:

```
task55 = () => {
  const task55word = document.getElementById("task55").value;
  const task55ans = document.getElementById("task55ans")
  const wordP = task55word.toLowerCase().match(/p/g);
  const wordT = task55word.toLowerCase().match(/t/g);
  const p = wordP.length;
  const t = wordT.length;
  if (p == t) {
 task55ans.textContent = 'equal';
  } else {
    task55ans.textContent = 'not equal';
  }
};
```

What I have done wrong?

Comment: The error means that you're trying to access the `.length` property of something without first determining that the something is not `null`.

Comment: you are missing value here: const task55ans = document.getElementById("task55ans")

Comment: I tried to follow your advices guys, I added:
 if (p != null || t != null)
but its not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. `match` returns `null` if nothing matches.

```
task55 = () => {
  const task55word = document.getElementById("task55").value;
  const task55ans = document.getElementById("task55ans");
  const wordP = task55word.toLowerCase().match(/p/g) || "";
  const wordT = task55word.toLowerCase().match(/t/g) || "";
  const p = wordP.length;
  const t = wordT.length;
  if (p == t) {
    task55ans.textContent = 'equal';
  } else {
    task55ans.textContent = 'not equal';
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried this code. Unfortunately its not working. It throws : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined at task55

Comment: ok, I updated a bit the code and works perfectly:

 if (task55word == "") {
    task55ans.textContent = 'empty';
  } else if (p == 0 && t == 0) {
    task55ans.textContent = 'not equal';
  } else if (p == t) {
    task55ans.textContent = 'equal';
  } 

I'm thinking, why its so important to put  || "" on the end of .match method? Could you explain the difference?  
Thank you for your time btw

Comment: because if nothing matches .match will return null and null.length will give error